# Inserting new item on ObservableCollection doesn't reflect on view, used DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My MainWindow.xml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:vm/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding addCommand}"/>
        <local:ModifiedControlView Items="{Binding People}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

My MainViewModel

```
public partial class vm : ObservableObject
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public vm()
        {
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void add()
        {
            People.Add(new Person { Name = "New", Age = 0 });
        }
    }
```

ModifiedControlView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp5.ModifiedControlView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

ModifiedControlView.xaml.c

```
public partial class ModifiedControlView : UserControl
    {
        public ModifiedControlView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>), typeof(ModifiedControlView), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ObservableCollection<Person> Items
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<Person>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

Why inserting new item on People Collection in VM, doesn't reflect in the view?

If I don't use the dependency property it works, but I need to use this collection inside a usercontrol with dependency property.

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` shouldn't this be `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`? You are setting the Items property but don't seem to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to bind the `ItemsSource` of the ListView in the UserControl's XAML to the `Items` property of the UserControl:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
```

---

As a note, it is not necessary to declare the `Items` property as an `ObservableCollection<Person>`.

It would provide greater flexibilty to use `IEnumerable<Person>` as property type. With an `ObservableCollection<Person>` as the source property type in the view model, notification events about collection changed would still be propagated to the control.

Comment: Even better is to define the property as an `IList<Person>`. For performance reasons it's recommended to prefer the `IList<T>` over `IEnumerable<T>` to avoid the internal wrapping of the `IEnumerable<T>` into an `IList<T>` (to create the `CollectionView`) by forcing the client to use an `IList` implementation as source collection.

Comment: Most collection classes implement IList anyway. Still I'd prefer to be able to pass the result of `System.Linq.Enumerable` query methods directly to an `IEnumerable<T>` property without the need for `.ToList()`.

Comment: Fair enough. I gave you an upvote to show that I was not criticizing the answer. This was not meant to criticize. I was just adding that enforcing an `IList<T>` as items source could improve the performance for the `ItemControl` and data binding to collections in general. When considering data binding, it would even better to enforce a `INotifyCollectionChanged` implementation (although this could be too much of an constraint).

Comment: From the convenience point of view, the binding engine will enumerate the `IEnumerable` in order to create the collection view. You are not losing anything by calling `ToList()` explicitly. In fact, by not finalizing the query (eager evaluation) you could introduce unwanted side effects in case your custom control does not immediately consumes the `IEnumerable` and the instance is modified outside by the owner after it was passed.

Comment: But in this case, where the value is immediately delegated to the internal `ListView` and the original value is not used in any other context, this details are of no relevance. But I think we should keep that in mind when passing around `IEnumerable` instances.